# Hiding Table Borders in Microsoft Word 2011 for Mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2011

I want to see the table borders in the document when I am editing it but not when I go to print the document. I am using Microsoft Office 2011 on a MacBook Pro. Is there any way to do this? Aside from the obvious option of turning off the borders when I want to print.

Comment: Showing the gridlines isn't enough?